# .htaccess remove .html file/directory priority rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite so you can access files without .html and without adding a trailing slash. here's the code being used:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html
```

But for my file structure on the server where I have this:

```
/public_html
          ..
          /beginners
           beginners.html
```

and inside /beginners folder there's other files, e.g.

```
          /beginners/page1.html
```

I need rewrites to work like this:

if user inputs url:
`website.com/beginners` - the server would return the contents of 
file `beginners.html` currently it returns the contents of the directory `/beginners` . so i need the server to first check if `beginners.html` exists, if yes - then server serves `beginners.html` not the directory `/beginners`

if the user accesses url `website.com/beginners/page1` the server should first check up if
`page1.html` exists in the folder beginners and if it finds the file `page1.html` then it serves the contents of the file `page1.html`

how can this be done?

Comment: so `/beginners/` - does that return the directory, or `/beginners.html`?

Comment: Actually, it seems you just need to get rid of the first rewrite condition - which specifies that the URI is not pointing to a directory.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan /beginners/ would return the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the .htaccess that does it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html
```